# Ambiguity in XにYがある

Tags: grammar, particle-に

> 彼女に一万円の借金があります。
> I have a debt to her of 10,000 yen. (given translation)

This (slightly awkward) English translation means that I owe the women 10,000 yen.
Is this sentence ambiguous? Without further context I would interpret this as meaning that the woman owes 10,000 yen to someone else.

Would changing に to には affect the meaning?

Comment: @Chocolate Thanks for the edit. Just out if interest, how did you know I'd cheated and used the wrong character for 「一」?  The two characters look identical to me.

Comment: Width and height, I guess. If you put them side by side ー一...
And the difference may be more pronounced in some fonts/environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence is ambiguous but almost theoretically (to me).

I would understand the sentence as (a) 'I owe 10000 yen to the woman', rather than (b) 'The woman owes 10000 yen to someone'.

> 彼女**には**一万円の借金があります

sounds more like (b) than (a).

> 彼女**は**一万円の借金があります

means only (b).